How to make a Page able to gets the properties or methods of current MainWindow in WinUI3
I am developing a WinUI 3 app that includes TabView. Now I want to create a new window when a tab is dragged out of the current window. But I cannot create another new window because App.m-window is set to the first created MainWindow. The code looks like this:
//App.xaml.cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App(){ this.InitializeComponent();}
    public static MainWindow m_window; //This is static so I can call it with "App.m_window"
    protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        m_window = new(); //m_window is set to the first created window
        m_window.Activate();
    }
}

//MainWindow.xaml.cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public TabView CurrentTabview;     //Some other properties
    public MainWindow(){ this.InitializeComponent();}
}

//Page.xaml.cs   This page is navigate by a tabview in MainWindow
public sealed partial class TabPage : Page
{
    public TabPage(){ 
        this.InitializeComponent();
        TabView Item = App.m_window.CurrentTabview; 
        // I have to call current "MainWindow" properties by using "App.m_window"
    }
}

That worked fine. But because I hope to do something like drag the tab out of the current window and automatically create a new window, I couldn't call App.m_window anymore. Or the page from two different window will call the same MainWindow.
I have tried the solution in How to retrieve the window handle of the current WinUI 3 MainWindow from a page in a frame in a NavigationView control on the MainWindow. But That doesn't work.
My previous solution of calling MainWindow was making it a static variable in App class. So now I tried with creating a variable ThisWindow in page and set it to App.m_window, so ThisWindow becomes local. Like this, but ThisWindow is "Null"
//Page.xaml.cs
private MainWindow ThisWindow;
void GetCurrentWindow(){ 
    ThisWindow = App.m_window;
    if ( ThisWindow != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("not null");
    }
    else { Debug.WriteLine("Null"); }
    // Output: Null
}

How can I solve it

If you make m_window static, it implicitly means there's only one window in the whole process. If you need to handle more than one window per app, you need to use a static collection of windows, for exmple create a dictionary of windows using a key that means something to your app for example.

If I create a dictionary than I have to pass the key to TabPage. How can I pass the key to tabpage with frame or something when the frame is navigating the tabpage?

Il ultimately depends on your code

Thank you, I have already found a way by override page.onnavigateto()

In App.xaml.cs create a static dictionary. Set the key to something like int, and the value is a MainWindow class item.
//App.xaml.cs
public static Dictionary<int, MainWindow> Windoww;

//Create a int for dictionary key
public int NewlyCreatedWindowNumber;

 public static MainWindow CreateNewWindow()
 {
     int NumberKeyToBeAssigned = NewlyCreatedWindleNumber + 1; //or just random
     MainWindow NewWindow = new();
     Windoww.Add(NumberKeyToBeAssigned, NewWindow);
     NewlyCreatedWindowNumber = NumberKeyToBeAssigned;
     NewWindow.SetWindowNumber( NumberKeyToBeAssigned); 
     // I create a int "WindowNumber" in "MainWindow", 
     // and this void sets the number to "NumberKeyToBeAssigned"
     NewWindow.Activate();
     return NewWindow;
 }

And make the frame inside MainWindow navigate TabPage with
Frame.Navigate(typeof(TabPage), WindowNumber);

Then I override OnNavigatedTo, it will be called when the frame navigates it, Then I can get the current MainWindow in TabPage with
//TabPage.xaml.cs
int Number;
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Number = (Int32)e.Parameter;
}

Mainwindow ThisWindow;

private void Setup()
{
    App.Windoww.TryGetValue(Number, out MainWindow ValueMainWindow);
    ThisWindow = ValueMainWindow; 
    //Then the current MainWindow is stored in "ThisWindow" variable
}

